# Why does ping resolve to a different address than traceroute? and lynx?

Tags: ping, traceroute, nslookup

We have a managed server with centos, recently it starts showing strange behavior:

```
root@server [/tmp]# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.8.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ord37s09-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.8.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=24.8 ms
```

So this looks quite good.

And here it becomes strange. We get our own server instead of the google server!

```
root@server [/tmp]# traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (75.102.21.14), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  server.plannersys.net (75.102.21.14)  0.041 ms  0.017 ms  0.015 ms
```

Nslookup, however, looks good:

```
root@server [/tmp]# nslookup
> www.google.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.217.8.196
> ^C
```

And wget and lynx also give us our own server.

```
root@server [/tmp]# wget https://www.google.com
--2017-12-04 11:50:56--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 75.102.21.14
Connecting to www.google.com|75.102.21.14|:443... connected.
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
        requested host name “www.google.com”.
To connect to www.google.com insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.

And with lynx:
SSL error:host(www.google.com)!=cert(troutaccess.com)-Continue? (y)
```

What can be the reason for this? Why do traceroute and wget and lynx use different addresses?

Comment: ask your sysadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not use fully-qualified domain names.  `www.google.com` is not a fully-qualified (human readable form) domain name.  It does not end with a dot.

You also have a search path of `plannersys.net.` configured in your DNS client library and a wildcard DNS resource record for `*.plannersys.net.`.

As a consequence of these, `wget` and `tranceroute` looked up the fully qualified domain name `www.google.com.plannersys.net.` and received the IP address 75.102.21.14 as the result.  Your DNS client library, remember, turns non-fully-qualified domain names into fully-qualified domain names using the configured search paths and then issues lookups for the fully-qualified names.

`nslookup` differed because it uses a different, internal, DNS client library.  Amusingly, this is one instance where it *did not* differ from `ping`, but that is probably because your DNS client library is configured with multiple proxy DNS servers that do not all present the same view of the DNS namespace, or you have something like `systemd-resolved` in the mix that is changing your DNS client configuration on the fly.  There is zero information about your DNS client library in your question, so there is not enough information from you for anyone to determine exactly why this is.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). *[What DNS name qualification is](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-name-qualification.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003). *[Why the results from `nslookup` are different to the operation of `ping`](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/nslookup-results-different-to-ping.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2004). *[DNS diagnosis tools](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-diagnosis-tools.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.